# Get values from a HashTable saved in a session variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, hashtable

In asp.net (vb.net) I have a Session variable that contain a HashTable

```
Dim products As Hashtable = New Hashtable
products("example") = "One product"
Session("products") = products
```

Now I want to obtain in client side with javascript, the value of  products("example").

I try this:

```
<SCRIPT>
    function ShowSessionValue() {
        // new object
        var sessionHashT = {};

        // asign HashTable stored in Session("products") to "sessionHashT"
        sessionHashT= '<%=Session("products")%>';

        // All alerts show "undefined" (but no errors):
        alert(sessionHashT("example"));
        alert(sessionHashT(example));
        alert(sessionHashT.example);
    };
</SCRIPT>
```

With a breakpoint I see that the value of sessionHashT is :

```
sessionHashT = 'System.Collections.Hashtable';
```

How I can get the values ​​of the HashTable with javascript?

Comment: You can store the session in a hidden field then retrieve that with javascript. Otherwise I dont think you can grab that session like that. But doing so will expose your session data in HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Dylan, but if I store data in a hidden field the data will be exposed too, because html field is client side. I don't care that these data are exposed , because otherwise I would not use javascript , would use codebehind . I want to access that data from the client side to accelerate the response.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you could serialize your `HashTable` to JSON to include in your script:

```js
// assign HashTable stored in Session("products") to "sessionHashT"
sessionHashT= JSON.parse('<%= New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Session("products"))%>');
```

I suppose you could get away with not parsing it (note the lack of quotes):

```js
// assign HashTable stored in Session("products") to "sessionHashT"
sessionHashT= <%= New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Session("products"))%>;
```

You should then be able to use the dotted form to access the items by key:

```js
alert(sessionHashT.example);
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, this options are interesting , I'll try and I comment .